# export environment variables for supervisord nobody user

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

i use supervisord to run applications like celery.

i use nobody user to run these apps. but they can't find environment variables.

for example, this is my celery.conf that uses nobody user. when i run celery with supervisord, it can't find DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable that i set before.

```
; ==================================                                                    
;  celery worker supervisor                                                             
; ==================================                                                    

[program:celery]                                                                        
command=/home/ubuntu/pl_env/bin/celery worker -A config --loglevel=INFO                 
directory=/home/ubuntu/petroline_django                                                 

user=nobody                                                                             
numprocs=1                                                                              
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log                                               
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log                                               
autostart=true                                                                          
autorestart=true                                                                        
startsecs=10                                                                            

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.                     
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.                                    
stopwaitsecs = 600                                                                      

; Causes supervisor to send the termination signal (SIGTERM) to the whole process group.
stopasgroup=true                                                                        

; Set Celery priority higher than default (999)                                         
; so, if rabbitmq is supervised, it will start first.                                   
priority=1000
```

Answer (score 1):

i found `environment` setting in [supervisord configuration file](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=environment), that can be used to solve this problem.